# How to remove image padding that is showing up unintentionally?

Tags: html, css, web

I have three images in a container that should be stacked seamlessly, but there is some padding occurring between them.

You can see the page here: http://www.arbitersoflight.net/media/

The three large buttons in the container on the left are the ones in question.

Here's the code for the container:

CSS

```
#mainBoxFull {
    background-image: url(/img/cont/mainfull.jpg);
    float: left;
    height: 560px; 
    width: 560px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="mainBoxFull">
    <img src="/img/btns/media/bgal.jpg" alt="screenshot" width="560" height="180" border="0" />
    <img src="/img/btns/media/bvid.jpg" alt="videos" width="560" height="200" border="0" />
    <img src="/img/btns/media/bsoon.jpg" alt="coming soon" width="560" height="180" border="0" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is, that images are inline-blocks. That is, spaces between them are counted. These spaces occur as padding to you. Use

```
#mainBoxFull img { display: block; }
```

and the problem should vanish. Alternatively, you can remove the white space in the source HTML between the div and the img elements (*all* white space).

Comment: Fine to do this as long as you dont need to put your images next to each other and having them wrap to the next line.

Comment: Why? The float and the width of the parent should be enough to let the images wrap. If you have different requirements (like a masonry-like layout), this is not the solution you should use. Try something like Flexbox instead, then.

Answer (score 6):

Another option to resolve the same problem is

```
#mainBoxFull{ font-size:0; }
```

it'll ignore all the white spaces in between. + you can se font size where ever you have the text.

Comment: I like this solution - it is clean and deals with the cause of the problem (that is there inline-block elements take into account line-spacing).