# Why aren't child divs staying on the same row unless I add extra width to parent?

Tags: html, css

I am making a header with 2 images as below:

```
<div id="header-logo">
    <div class="header-logo"><img src="logo.png"></div>
    <div class="header-name"><img src="logo-name.png"></div>
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
#header-logo { width: 538px; margin: 0 auto; }
#header-logo div { display: inline; height: auto; }
#header-logo div.header-logo { width: 183px; }
#header-logo div.header-name { width: 355px; }
```

The problem is that unless I make the parent div (`#header-logo`) 542px or bigger the child divs go below each other, I don't understand why as 183 + 355 = 538, where is the extra 4 pixels coming from?

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760002/how-to-remove-image-padding-that-is-showing-up-unintentionally basically adding display block to your images.

Comment: Thanks guys, removing the white space between the div's solved it. I've never had the problem before, maybe I've just never done this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with the spaces that are characteristic of inline elements.

If you're writing text in a `<p>` element and you hit the space bar or add a line break, that space is rendered by the browser. This same behavior applies to all inline elements, like images and inputs.

The fastest way to resolve the issue is:

1. Add `font-size: 0` to the parent element. In your code, just do:
   `div { font-size: 0; }`, OR
2. Remove all spaces and line breaks between elements:

   `<div id="header-logo"><div class="header-logo"><img src="logo.png"></div><div class="header-name"><img src="logo-name.png"></div></div>`

Other options include *negative margins*, *omitting closing tags*, *using comment tags*, *floats* and *flexbox*. See this article for details on each method:

- [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

For more details about this issue see:

- [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B, removing the white space solved it!